# Swift regular and bold font together in textview

Tags: swift, fonts, uitextfield, uitextview

I am trying to use regular and bold font together in textview. When user types, user can type regular font or (there is a button to write bold font) user can tap a button to type bold font. How user can type regular and bold font in same textview? Which method can I use for it?

This is what I want: [image: example]

This is my code:

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    
    var partOne = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString()
    
    let boldFontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)]
    let normalFontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
    let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()
    
    if boldButtonTap == false {
        partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text, attributes: normalFontAttributes)  
    } else {
        partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text, attributes: boldFontAttributes)    
    }
    combination.append(partOne)
    combination.append(partTwo)
    textView.attributedText = combination
}
```

Comment: If you are having trouble with this imagine when you try to set it to bold and italic at the same time. Btw this is not a code writing service. You should show some minimal effort otherwise it would look like you are asking us to do your homework. Please edit your question, show what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the text field's `attributedText` property to set its contents to styled text. (The attributedText property takes values of type `NSAttributedString`
Creating a text editor that lets the user apply styles to the contents of a text view is a big task, and beyond the scope of an SO answer.

(Note that UITextField also has properties like `typingAttributes` that lets you change the attributes used to enter new text. You can use that if the user sets the font to bold before entering new text.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Duncan.  How can I change the attributes use to enter new text?

Comment: By setting the `typingAttributes`, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var normalText = "normal text" 
var boldText  = "bold text" 
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:normalText)
let textField = UITextField()

var attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)]
var boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: boldText, attributes:attrs)

attributedString.append(boldString)

// for normal text
textField.text = normalText
// for normal text with bold
textField.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Even thought the result is close for what is being asked you should set the font withSymbolicTraits `.traitBold` instead of just using a bold system font.

Comment: Did you check your code? It doesn’t look like contains returns a font